# HTML5 & XHTML role attribute question

Tags: xhtml, html

Does the role attribute have defined values if so can you tell what they are?

Or can I create my own values for the role attribute if is so are they case-sensitive do they have to be letters can there be numbers or both?

Or can you have both defined values and user created values.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170356/what-values-can-the-html5-xhtml-role-attribute-have

Answer (score 3):

A quick google turned up this: [Semantics in HTML 5](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/semanticsinhtml5).

According to that site, the values of the role attribute are a space separated list of words from the [XHTML Vocabulary](http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/).

Comment: Thanks Benoit. The specific URL that documents them is: http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#role_definitions