# HTML language switcher accessibility

Tags: html, wai-aria

Is there any aria-something or a role to add in a language switch link ?
For exemple, I put two links in the footer to change the current language.

```
<a href="/language/switch/fr">Fr</a>
<a href="/language/switch/uk">Uk</a>
```

I there any semantic tag to add to this links ?

Comment: Please post your own research efforts, what did you do to find a solution?'
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I haven't found anything in the aria documentation that could match my problem. By the way, I'm not sure there's a correct tag for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example:

```
<a href="/language/switch/fr" lang="fr" hreflang="fr">Fr</a>
```

See https://www.nomensa.com/blog/2010/7-tips-for-multi-lingual-website-accessibility for more info.

[lang attribute doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang):

> The `lang` global attribute helps define the language of an element: the
> language that non-editable elements are written in, or the language
> that the editable elements should be written in by the user.

[hreflang attribute doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-hreflang):

> Hints at the human language of the linked URL. No built-in functionality. Allowed values are the same as the global `lang` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you think I can add the switch role too ?

    <a href="/language/switch/fr" lang="fr" hreflang="fr" role="switch">Fr</a>

Comment: 'Switch' is not a valid value for role. Use 'navigation'. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170356/what-values-can-the-html5-xhtml-role-attribute-have

Comment: switch certainly is a valid role.  see https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#switch.  but it's not appropriate for this situation.  if you have a component that works like a checkbox, then you can use it, but the sample code was just two links.  i would **not** use a navigation role on those either.  navigation is more about navigating through the site.  the language links are just changing the language of the page and don't really navigate you anywhere.

Comment: Switch role: "A type of checkbox that represents on/off values, as opposed to checked/unchecked values." Damn, how did I miss that, sorry. Thanks @slugolicious

Comment: `lang` attribute's value should match the language of the content of the tag. So it should be used like: <a href="/language/switch/fr" lang="fr" hreflang="fr">Français</a> or <a href="/language/switch/fr" lang="en" hreflang="fr">French</a>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the rest of your code but if you don't have any text like `Choose language` before these links then it is advisable to add an aria-label to each link describing what the link is doing, like:

```
<a href="/language/switch/fr" aria-label="Visit our perfect site in French">Fr</a>
```

This way the screen-readers will override the link text and read out loud the aria-label which is very helpful for blind users or users with visual impairments.

A piece of advice: Using the full name of the language instead of the initials can help communicate clearly what the lang is in case of users who have the auto-translate ON. Check [this article](https://uxdesign.cc/my-take-on-language-selectors-945caceb58f7) for more.

Comment: The accepted answer about using the `lang` attribute is actually not quite right for this situation since the link only displayed the letters `Fr`. Having a screen reader switch to a French accent when it sees `Fr` will not help the screen reader user. If the text were `Français`, then absolutely use the `lang` attribute. In your recommendation, @nasia, you would cause a WCAG 2.5.3 issue since now the `aria-label` does not contain the text within the link, which is only `Fr`. The comments in the accepted answer by @4esn0k are good advice.

Comment: @slugolicious thank you for bringing up this guideline! I am just wondering what would be an acceptable solution for a label if they have to make use of the initials and not the full name of the language. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would do something like this: `<span>Fr <span class="sr-only" lang="fr">Français</span></span>`. This will satisfy 2.5.3 and give the screen reader a language to announce.